# duplicate symbol error with -ObjC linker flag

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I try to implement a third part SDK (Socialize) to my iOS App.For doing that I use CocoaPods.I also added the Swiftype SDK and had to add -ObjC to other linker flags section in Build Settings. When I build the app it shows the following error:

```
`duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation
[...]`
```

If I remove the ObjC linker flag, the app work perfectly but Swiftype stops working.
I've already try to include $(inherited) to my target settings but I still have build errors.
How can I fix that ? 
Thank You

Comment: Don't post the same question twice!

Comment: Sorry I have removed the other one.

Comment: list all external non-system frameworks you are link with